# Eliminating duplicates in an array of ints

Tags: java, array

```
  public static Integer[] eliminateDuplicate(int[] a) {
        if (a == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            // include last element by default, if not the last element, do the check for duplication.
            if (i == a.length - 1 || a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
                list.add(a[i]);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you added some comments about your intent and any problems you encountered or things you are unsure of.  Code is not, in itself, documentation.

Comment: Please add a comment detailing what you want improvement on in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesn't handle duplicates in the entire array, but only in consecutive entries.  A better name might be `collapseConsecutive`.

The input is an `int[]`, but the return type is `Integer[]`.  Consistency would be nice.

You don't need to throw `NullPointerException` explicitly.  If `a` is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` will automatically be thrown when it tries to do `a.length`.  If you really want to explicitly validate your arguments, you could throw `IllegalArgumentException` instead.

A micro-optimization would be to change to

```
if (i == 0 || a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
    list.add(a[i]);
}
```

Comparing against 0 is simpler than comparing against `a.length - 1` since the JVM (and CPUs) has an `ifeq` opcode for doing just that.  To compare against `a.length - 1`, the bytecode would have to load `a.length - 1` into a register before comparing — and that is assuming that the compiler is smart enough to compute `a.length - 1` just once.

Comment: See, JD?  It's not just me not being sure of your intent.

Answer (score 2):

Minor point - don't use an old c-style for loop to iterate through an array unless you absolutely have to (and you don't have to here).  Please, this is 2013 not 2003 - generics have been here for a decade.  You can use foreach:

```
if a.length > 0 {
  int lastValue = a[0];
  list.add(lastValue);
  for (int i: a) {  
    if (i != lastValue) {
      lastValue = i;
      list.add(i);
    }
  } 
}
```

Using old-style c-loops always opens a possibility of a stupid error.  Since you can cache the last value you inserted in the array, you don't have to use the old-style loop.  My loop also has just one check, and that check is cheaper to do than yours (or 200_success's) because it doesn't need to do the array look-up.

Note that my solution inserts the first value without checking, while yours does this for the final one.  Not only is this more logical (I think), it eliminated a check from the logic.

Your method is called **eliminateDuplicates** but it will only do that if the list has already been sorted.  If that was not done, it will only eleminiate *sequential* duplicates.  That is, it will turn **(3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3)** into **(3,1,2,3,4,3)**.

Is that what you want?  The fact that you always keep the last member implies this, but how can we be sure?  If it *is* so, either document the intent or maybe name the function more clearly (e.g. **eliminateAdjacentDuplicates**).

If you want to eliminate all duplicates, then you could start by sorting the array.  But since you are using the collections api, why not use a set?

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Then you just need to turn the set back into an array.

I may have gone on at unnecessary length, but that's because you didn't properly document your intent.  Please, if you learn nothing else, learn this.

Comment: Since you accepted 200_success's answer, I guess you wanted to eliminate adjacent duplicates ;)  But I've left my original comments in, despite having edited my code for clarity.